# How to solve the integration to get the desired answer

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to prove the following:

If
$$\int \frac{adx}{(ax-2)\sqrt{(ax-1)}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}}$$

then show that $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{a}{2}\left(1+sech({\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}}})\right)$

Given, at $y=0$, $x=1/a$.

**Approach**

I have assumed $ax-1= \cosh^2z$ then $ax-2=\sinh^2z$, $adx=2\cosh{z}\sinh{z} dz$

Then we get,
$$2\int \frac{dz}{\sinh {z}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}}$$

But I failed to show the desired.

Comment: You are on the right way, note that $\int\frac{dz}{\sinh z}=-\text{artanh}\,(\cosh z)+C$.

Comment: @mickep Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt{ax-1}$, then $x=\frac{u^2+1}{a}\,\,\,$ and $\,\,\,dx=\frac{2u}{a}du$, so
\begin{align}
\int\frac{adx}{(ax-2)\sqrt{ax-1}}&=\int\frac{a\left(\frac{2u}{a}\right)du}{(u^2-1)u}\\
&=\int\frac{2du}{u^2-1}\\
&=\int\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)du
\end{align}

You can do the remaining part.

Comment: A Hint to solve the problem was put $ax−1=cosh^2 z$. Please help with this substitution.

Comment: @mickep Please help me here also with the above hints.

Comment: rama_ran, I don't understand what you want me to do. I suggest you do the integration like Mario G suggests. If you want to go the way with inverse hyperbolic functions, I think you should look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424957/integrate-int-fraca-dr2r-a-sqrtra-r) again.

Comment: @mickep I want to use the substitution $ax−1=cosh^2 z$ to prove the problem. Please help as I struck at a point.